# Compute the limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{n^2[\cos(x/n^2)-1]}{1+x^3}dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, analysis

> How to calculate the following limit:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{n^2[\cos(x/n^2)-1]}{1+x^3}dx.$$

---

I have tried dominated convergence theorem but I cannot find a proper dominated function. I also tried applying the residue theorem, but if we choose the upper-semi circle as the contour then the integrand is not an even function. And I tried to expand the function into power series, but nothing helps. Can someone give me a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^3}$. Then $f$ is integrable on $[0, \infty)$. Indeed, $f$ is bounded by $f(0)$ and $f(x) \asymp 1/x^2$ as $x\to\infty$. Now by integration by parts,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2(\cos(x/n^2)-1)}{1+x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x
&= -\int_{0}^{\infty} n^2(\cos(x/n^2)-1)f'(x) \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \underbrace{\left[ -n^2(\cos(x/n^2)-1)f(x) \right]_{0}^{\infty}}_{=0} - \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x/n^2)f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Now by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2(\cos(x/n^2)-1)}{1+x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x
= - \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(x/n^2)f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= 0. $$

---

*Addendum.* A more detailed analysis, with a bit of help from Mathematica 11, shows that

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2(\cos(x/n^2)-1)}{1+x^3}\,\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\log n + \frac{3}{4} - \frac{\gamma}{2} + o(1) \right) $$

as $n\to\infty$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By letting $t=x/n^2$, we have that
$$\begin{align}
0\leq -I_n&:=\int_0^\infty\frac{n^2[1-\cos(x/n^2)]}{1+x^3}dx\\
&=
n^4\int_0^\infty\frac{[1-\cos(t)]}{1+n^6 t^3}dt\\
&\leq
n^4\int_0^1\frac{t^2/2}{1+n^6t^3}dt
+n^4\int_1^\infty\frac{2}{n^6 t^3}dt\\
&=\frac{[\ln(1+n^6t^3)]_0^1}{6n^2}
+\frac{1}{n^2}\left[-\frac{1}{t^2}\right]_1^\infty\\
&=\frac{\ln(1+n^6)}{6n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align}$$
where we used the fact that $0\leq 1-\cos(t)\leq \min(t^2/2,2)$.

Now it should be easy to see that the RHS goes to zero as $n\to +\infty$.
As a matter of fact, the above inequality implies that $I_n\in O(\ln(n)/n^2)$ and therefore even $n^aI_n$ goes to zero for $a<2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{n^2[\cos(x/n^2)-1]}{1+x^3}dx$$
for ease I will let:
$$f(x,n)=\frac{\cos(x/n^2)-1}{1+x^3}$$
and so we can say:
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^\infty f(x,n)dx}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
now since this is a $\frac 00$ situation we can use L'Hopitals rule and say:
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[-\int_0^\infty\frac{x\sin(x/n^2)}{1+x^3}dx\right]$$
where we can observe that for $n\to\infty,\sin(x/n^2)\to0$ and so $L\to0$